# AppID not recognized, but it shows up correctly in the source code (Comment box)

Tags: facebook, comments, app-id

I have integrated Facebooks Comment box into my page. I copied the generated code into my page.
The App-ID shows up correctly in the sourcecode, but Facebook does not recognize it.
I am treated as admin, because my UserID is also in the sourcecode, so I see the moderation view. But if I switch to "settings" on the embedded comment box, I get this error message:

```
removed
```

Also if I enter a comment, I can edit it on the embedded box directly, but it will not show up in the Comment Moderation Tool on Facebook.

Here is my embedded code:

```
  removed
```

I also tried the debug tool. It displays an "Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed" error, but this seems not to be the app-id problem. Also the debugger displays my User/Moderator-ID but no app-ID.

Can anyone help me? :/
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the missing meta tag:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="APPID_HERE">
```